# I am unable to draw image on Canvas in J2ME

Tags: java, image, canvas, java-me, loadimage

I am try to load image on Canvas but it giving `java.io.IOException exception`. I don't know in which folder i have to put image. but right now i am putting image in F`:\New Folder\DrawImage\src\Waterfall.png.` i am using netbean editor for coding. reference code from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0430__J2ME/Drawimage.htm)

`public class Midlet extends MIDlet {`

```
public Display display;

public void startApp() {

    Canvas obj = new DrawImage();

    display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    display.setCurrent(obj);

}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}

public class DrawImage extends Canvas{

    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        try {

            System.out.println("111111");
            Image image = Image.createImage("/Waterfall.png");
            if(image != null)
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, Graphics.TOP | Graphics.LEFT);
            else
                System.out.println("2222");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }   
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: Image image = Image.createImage("Waterfall.png"); - remove "/" OR you can create res folder in your project, add it into Resource, and call Image.createImage("/Waterfall.png");

Comment: `Image.createImage(filename)` only loads files from within your JAR file (which is probably also what you want). If you want to load from SD card, then you should use FileConnection API, but I don't think that's what you want.
Try placing your `Waterfall.png` file either in the root directory of your source, or else in a folder with the name `res`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make new folder at project folder and rename as `rsc` and copy and paste image in this folder. after that you need to go project properties and click on `Build -> Libraries and Resources` on that window you find `Add Folder` button click on that button locate you `rsc` folder and click ok. then run your project.